# Building a custom accordion menu from stock code

Tags: javascript, html, css, menu, accordion

I've been trying to use an Accordion menu for a list of R Shiny dashboards I have. The idea is that clicking the list entry expands a description out in an accordion fashion.

I'm using the stock animated version of the [accordion menu from W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_accordion.asp) and trying to adapt it to my needs. However, I need the description portion to expand to larger, because I want the background of the description to be a preview image of the dashboard.

However, I'm having difficulty making it work with this stock version, due to the way they facilitate the expansion of the description part.

Here is my code thus far for what I currently have, which is essentially the animated version of the W3Schools

```js
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].onclick = function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.maxHeight){
      panel.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
    } 
  }
}
```

```css
/* Style the buttons that are used to open and close the accordion panel */
button.accordion {
  background-color: #eee;
  color: #444;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  transition: 0.4s;
}
button.accordion.active, button.accordion:hover {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

/* Add a background color to the button if it is clicked on (add the .active class with JS), and when you move the mouse over it (hover) */
/* Style the accordion panel. Note: hidden by default */
div.previewPanel {
  padding: 0 18px;
  background-color: white;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<button class="accordion">Thing1</button>
<div class="previewPanel">
  <p>Preview image goes here</p>
</div>
<button class="accordion">Thing2</button>
<div class="previewPanel">
  <p>Preview image goes here</p>
</div>
<button class="accordion">Thing3</button>
<div class="previewPanel">
  <p>Preview image goes here</p>
</div>
<button class="accordion">Thing4</button>
<div class="previewPanel">
  <p>Preview image goes here</p>
</div>
<button class="accordion">Thing5</button>
<div class="previewPanel">
  <p>Preview image goes here</p>
</div>
<button class="accordion">Thing6</button>
<div class="previewPanel">
  <p>Preview image goes here</p>
</div>
```

And here is a link to a [codepen](https://codepen.io/maxbrn/pen/XeYBgy) with elements labeled in a way that might better convey what I'm trying to do.

The ask is: What can I do to what I have so that I can change the size of the expanded area, or what might I use that would work better? The exec types really like animations and sleek design, because they do show some of this stuff to potential clients.

Comment: Check the ans.....

Answer (score 0):

i recommend to use Bootstrap for a nice visual Output.

[W3 school Bootstrap Accordion](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_collapse.asp)

[Bootstrap Accordion Example](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_collapsible_accordion&stacked=h)

Comment: he looking for background image in accordions with some space

Comment: True, but I'm also looking just for ways to control the height and other attributes while having the animation. These examples are very helpful and I might just dump the regular Accordion for the Bootstrap one.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].onclick = function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.maxHeight){
      panel.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
    } 
  }
}
```

```css
/* Style the buttons that are used to open and close the accordion panel */

.previewPanel{
  background-image:url("http://www.newdesignfile.com/postpic/2010/01/web-page-header-design_201166.png");
}

button.accordion {
  background-color: #eee;
  color: #444;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  transition: 0.4s;
}
button.accordion.active, button.accordion:hover {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

/* Add a background color to the button if it is clicked on (add the .active class with JS), and when you move the mouse over it (hover) */
/* Style the accordion panel. Note: hidden by default */
div.previewPanel {
  padding: 0 18px;
  background-color: white;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<button class="accordion">Thing1</button>
<div class="previewPanel">
  <p>Preview image goes here</p>
</div>
<button class="accordion">Thing2</button>
<div class="previewPanel">
  <p>Preview image goes here</p>
</div>
<button class="accordion">Thing3</button>
<div class="previewPanel">
  <p>Preview image goes here</p>
</div>
<button class="accordion">Thing4</button>
<div class="previewPanel">
  <p>Preview image goes here</p>
</div>
<button class="accordion">Thing5</button>
<div class="previewPanel">
  <p>Preview image goes here</p>
</div>
<button class="accordion">Thing6</button>
<div class="previewPanel">
  <p>Preview image goes here</p>
</div>
```